# A few questions about color segmentation with L*a*b*

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to identify the onset of red/yellow color above the inner cone in the following image with color segmentation.

[image: Inner light blue and outer dark blue cone and a red/yellow region above the inner cone]

To do this, I implemented [lab color segmentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-the-l-a-b-color-space.html),

```
clear all
close all
%Plot image
flame = imread('flamePic.JPG');
flame = imrotate(flame,270);
figure(1), imshow(flame), title('Flame');


%Find color of small region
load regioncoordinates;

nColors = 6;
sample_regions = false([size(flame,1) size(flame,2) nColors]);

for count = 1:nColors
  sample_regions(:,:,count) = roipoly(flame,region_coordinates(:,1,count),...
                                      region_coordinates(:,2,count));
end

%imshow(sample_regions(:,:,2)),title('sample region for red');

%Convert your fabric RGB image into an L*a*b* image using makecform and applycform.
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab_fabric = applycform(flame,cform);

%Calculate the mean 'a*' and 'b*' value for each area that you extracted with roipoly. These values serve as your color markers in 'a*b*' space.
a = lab_fabric(:,:,2);
b = lab_fabric(:,:,3);
color_markers = repmat(0, [nColors, 2]);

for count = 1:nColors
  color_markers(count,1) = mean2(a(sample_regions(:,:,count)));
  color_markers(count,2) = mean2(b(sample_regions(:,:,count)));
end

%For example, the average color of the red sample region in 'a*b*' space is
disp(sprintf('[%0.3f,%0.3f]',color_markers(2,1),color_markers(2,2)));

%Create an array that contains your color labels, i.e., 0 = background, 1 = red, 2 = green, 3 = purple, 4 = magenta, and 5 = yellow.
color_labels = 0:nColors-1;

%Initialize matrices to be used in the nearest neighbor classification.
a = double(a);
b = double(b);
distance = repmat(0,[size(a), nColors]);

%Perform classification
for count = 1:nColors
  distance(:,:,count) = ( (a - color_markers(count,1)).^2 + ...
                      (b - color_markers(count,2)).^2 ).^0.5;
end

[value, label] = min(distance,[],3);
label = color_labels(label);
clear value distance;

%Step 4: Display Results of Nearest Neighbor Classification
%The label matrix contains a color label for each pixel in the fabric image. Use the label matrix to separate objects in the original fabric image by color.

rgb_label = repmat(label,[1 1 3]);
segmented_images = repmat(uint8(0),[size(flame), nColors]);

for count = 1:nColors
  color = flame;
  color(rgb_label ~= color_labels(count)) = 0;
  segmented_images(:,:,:,count) = color;
end

%Demonstrate red objects
figure(2),
imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,1)), title('Color1');
figure(3),
imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,2)), title('Color2');
figure(4),
imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,3)), title('Color3');
figure(5),
imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,4)), title('Color4');
figure(6),
imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,5)), title('Color5');
figure(7),
imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,6)), title('Color6');
```

Running this algorithm on the above image gives me the following:

[image]
[image]

I am not exactly sure what color is being separated, but there is plenty of red that has not been identified. In addition, I am unable to distinguish between the inner, whiter cone, and the outer, dark blue cone. I think it has to do with how I sample the colors and the regions  of interest with `roipoly` but I am not sure how I can improve it. Do you have any tips on how I can improve the segmentation for this specific application?

Comment: are you required to do the segmentation only with lab color space? Perhaps you can try hsv space as well.

Comment: Well, not really. What are the advantages of using hsv space over Lab?