# Colour Segmentation by l*a*b

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, segment

I'm using the code on the MatLab website, "Color-Based Segmentation Using the L*a*b* Color Space": 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-the-l-a-b-color-space.html

So I'm trying to select some areas myself instead of using the "load region_coordinates", using roipoly(fabric), but i get stuck. How do I save coordinates of the polygon I just drew? I'm actually following advice from lennon310 at Solution II, bottom of page:
[A few questions about color segmentation with L*a*b*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668687/a-few-questions-about-color-segmentation-with-lab/21710828#21710828)

I'm not sure when to save `region_coordinates` and do `size(region_coordinates,1)`

I made the following changes **(Step 1)**:

1) Removed "load region_coordinates"

2) Added "region_coordinates = roipoly(fabric);"

Here's the code:

`
%% Step 1

```
fabric = imread(file);

figure(1);                                                                   %Create figure window. "If h is not the handle and is not the Number property value of an existing figure, but is an integer, then figure(h) creates a figure object and assigns its Number property the value h."
imshow(fabric)
title('fabric')



%load regioncoordinates; % 6 marices(?) labelled val(:,:,1-6), 5x2 (row x column)
region_coordinates = roipoly(fabric);

nColors = 6;
sample_regions = false([size(fabric,1) size(fabric,2) nColors]); %Initializing an Image Dimension, 3x3 (:,:,:) to zero? Zeros() for arrays only I guess.
                        %Size one is column, size two is row?
for count = 1:nColors
  sample_regions(:,:,count) = roipoly(fabric,region_coordinates(:,1,count),region_coordinates(:,2,count));

end

figure, imshow(sample_regions(:,:,2)),title('sample region for red');
```

%%Step 2

```
% Convert your fabric RGB image into an L*a*b* image using rgb2lab .

lab_fabric = rgb2lab(fabric);


%Calculate the mean a* and b* value for each area that you extracted with roipoly. These values serve as your color markers in a*b* space.

a = lab_fabric(:,:,2);
b = lab_fabric(:,:,3);
color_markers = zeros([nColors, 2]);%... I think this is initializing a 6x2 blank(0) array for colour storage. 6 for colours, 2 for a&b colourspace.

for count = 1:nColors
  color_markers(count,1) = mean2(a(sample_regions(:,:,count))); %Label for repmat, Marker for 
  color_markers(count,2) = mean2(b(sample_regions(:,:,count)));
end

%For example, the average color of the red sample region in a*b* space is

fprintf('[%0.3f,%0.3f] \n',color_markers(2,1),color_markers(2,2));
```

%% Step 3: Classify Each Pixel Using the Nearest Neighbor Rule
    %

```
color_labels = 0:nColors-1;

% Initialize matrices to be used in the nearest neighbor classification.

a = double(a);
b = double(b);
distance = zeros([size(a), nColors]); 


%Perform classification, Elucidean Distance.

for count = 1:nColors
  distance(:,:,count) = ( (a - color_markers(count,1)).^2 + (b - color_markers(count,2)).^2 ).^0.5;
end

[~, label] = min(distance,[],3);
label = color_labels(label);
clear distance;
```

%% Step 4: Display Results of Nearest Neighbor Classification
    % 
    % The label matrix contains a color label for each pixel in the fabric image. 
    % Use the label matrix to separate objects in the original fabric image by color.

```
rgb_label = repmat(label,[1 1 3]);
segmented_images = zeros([size(fabric), nColors],'uint8');

for count = 1:nColors
  color = fabric;
  color(rgb_label ~= color_labels(count)) = 0;
  segmented_images(:,:,:,count) = color;
end

%figure, imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,1)), title('Background of Fabric');
%Looks different somehow.
figure, imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,2)), title('red objects');

figure, imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,3)), title('green objects');

figure, imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,4)), title('purple objects');

figure, imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,5)), title('magenta objects');

figure, imshow(segmented_images(:,:,:,6)), title('yellow objects');



`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the coordinates of the polygon using output arguments in the call to `roipoly`. You can then get a binary mask of the polygon, as well as vertices coordinates if you want.

Simple example demonstrating:

```
clear
clc
close all

A = imread('cameraman.tif');

figure;
imshow(A)

%// The vertices of the polygon are stored in xi and yi;
%// PolyMask is a binary image where pixels == 1 are white.
[polyMask, xi, yi] = roipoly(A);
```

This looks like this:

[image]

And if you wish to see the vertices with the binary mask:

```
%// display polymask
imshow(polyMask)
hold on

%// Highlight vertices in red
scatter(xi,yi,60,'r')
hold off
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

So to summarize:

1) The polygon's vertices are stored in xi and yi.

2) You can plot the binaryMask of the polygon using `imshow(polyMask)`.

3) If you need the coordinates of the white pixels, you can use something like this:

```
[row_white,col_white] = find(polyMask == 1);
```

You're then good to go. Hope that helps!